# is there way to change label color and active tab border-bottom color?

Tags: html, css, angular-material

here is my html:

```
 <md-tabs  md-dynamic-height >
                    <div>
                        <md-tab label="Tab 1">

                        </md-tab>
                        <md-tab label="Tab 2" >

                        </md-tab>
                        <md-tab  label="Tab 3" >

                        </md-tab>

                    </div>
                </md-tabs>
```

Need to change labels color and border-bottom color when clicked on tab.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "border bottom" it's created using an `<md-ink-bar>`, here the default selector:

```
md-tabs.md-default-theme md-ink-bar, md-tabs md-ink-barr{
    color: rgb(255,82,82);
    background: rgb(255,82,82);
}
```

here the label active/inactive:

```
md-tabs .md-tab.md-active{
    color: rgb(16,108,200);
}

md-tabs.md-default-theme .md-tab, md-tabs .md-tab{
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
}
```

For a correct style customization you can create a custom theme that will override the standard colors without create custom css, check the [DOC](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/03_configuring_a_theme)

Comment: Hi your solution works only when I add theme class `.md-default-theme md-ink-bar`.
How to set color that will be valid for any theme? Ty.

Comment: is the selector `md-tabs md-ink-bar, md-tabs md-ink-barr` not working?

Answer (score 0):

add script and css.

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div md-tab").click(function(){
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    });
    </script>

    <style>
    .active{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        color: #f44336;
    }
    </style>
```